# How to create an enum whose scope is limited to only one .m file?

Tags: objective-c, enums, scope

I usually use this code

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum)
{
    MyEnumItem1,
    MyEnumItem2,
    MyEnumItem3,
};
```

How can I limit the scope of the `enum`?

Answer (score 0):

To limit the scope of your enum to 1 file. You could put your enum declaration in that .m file rather than .h file.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, MyEnum)
{
    MyEnumItem1,
    MyEnumItem2,
    MyEnumItem3,
};


@interface ViewController ()
@property (nonatomic) MyEnum enumItem;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.enumItem = MyEnumItem1;
}

@end
```